# Sharepoint 2013 List - users only view their own Items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I have a SharePoint 2013 list where I need users to only see the items they have created. It is a user support ticket system so users need to be able to add tickets using the form I created but then should not be able to see tickets others have created. Any idea how to do this? I know it is in Advanced Settings in SharePoint 2010 but cannot find this setting in 2013.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

In Advanced Settings of a **Custom List** you will have the option to set Item-Level Permissions, if you have a **Library** this option will not be available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the view of the list to filter on field `Created by`. Insert [Me] into the criteria. Then when someone goes to the list they will only see the items they created.